# MacOS fails to get the file name from download response in ASP. NET Core

Tags: asp.net, macos, httpresponse

I have an API entry which returns `Task<DownloadResponse>` (simple class containing only FileName and DownloadUrl).
I use the following method to give back the result, which works fine in Windows and Linux:

```
return new DownloadResponse()
{
    FileName = displayedFileName,
    DownloadUrl = downloadBaseUrl + downloadLink
};
```

Where `FileName` is something like `dateFrom-dateTo.zip`, while `DownloadUrl` is something like `http://localhost/download/file/{hash}`. On windows machines I am able to download the file with name `FileName`, while on MacOS the downloaded files name is the `hash` at the end of the `DownloadUrl` (although the file content is correct).

What might be the issue here?

Comment: You should probably be returning one of the File specific result types e.g. `FileResult`, `FileContentResult`, etc. assuming you're using ASP.NET Core.